# Pixel 6 can't connect to n48 (5g SA)

Tags: android-12, cellular-radio, google-pixel-6

TL;DR
I have a **Google Pixel 6** and I am able to see my private PLMN but attempting to connect will show instant text, "couldn't connect". No logs in my 5g core, and no registration attempt.

Issue

- GSM Arena shows that Pixel 6 can do n48
- I've verified that the Pixel 6 can decode SIB1 in n48 and see the test network name "Open5GCore"
- Attempt to connect provides no logs in the core using the following
  radio imp files (Android still using version 12.1)

  1. 12.1.0 (SQ3A.220705.003.A3, Jul 2022, Verizon, Verizon MVNOs)
  2. 12.1.0 (SQ3A.220705.004, Jul 2022)
  3. 13.0.0 (TP1A.220905.004, Sep 2022)

I'm starting to think that the phone has a carrier block at the software level that I don't have the knowledge to verify.
In the US, there aren't any carriers who use n48, maybe some flag hasn't been set true yet via OTA images?
FCC branded it for private use, maybe Google intentionally blocks the capability?

I'm writing this late so I'll upload my logcat in the morning.

Comment: Also cross-posted on XDA Forum: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/pixel-6-cant-connect-to-n48-5g-sa.4501163/